# What does this Method declaration/definition mean? (something to do with passing an array?)

Tags: c++, function, declaration

Hi I was stumbling through legacy code, and I came across a wierd method definition/declaration. I have an educated guess of what it does, but I cannot be 100% sure yet.

declaration:

```
const SomeEnumeratedId (&SomeMethod() const)[SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE];
```

definition

```
const SomeEnumeratedId (&SomeClass::SomeMethod() const)[SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE]
{
    return someMemberArray;
}
```

My best guess is that it is passing a reference to someMemberArray and that it is guaranteeing that it is of size SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE, but I have never seen the [] notation after the method declaration as it appears, and there are so many parentheses.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the declaration of a `const` member function taking no parameters and returning a reference to an array of `SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE` `const` `SomeEnumeratedId`s.

It looks easier to understand with a `typedef`.

```
typedef const SomeEnumeratedId SomeArrayType[SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE];

SomeArrayType& SomeClass::SomeMethod() const
{
    return someMemberArray;
}
```

Comment: So does the [SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE] after the method tell the calling function that the returned reference references an array of that length? That's the part that confuses me the most as I've never seen that part in a function declaration. I've only seen arrays passed as references or pointers without that at the end.

Comment: @Michael: Yes. It's part of the return type declaration.

Comment: Think of the declaration of an array: `int x[k];` Now a reference to an array: `int (&y)[k];` Now to declare a function that returns a reference to an array we replace `y` with something that looks like a function call: `int (&(z())[k];` z is a function returning a reference to an array. Sane people use a `typedef` at this point even though typedefs to arrays can be misleading in some cases.

Comment: @Michael: Yea, it's a consequence of C's utterly backwards type declaration syntax. It's similar to how, when doing an array typedef, you write this: `typedef int myArrayType[3];`, with the `[3]` after the new typename, not the original.

Answer (score 0):

That weird notation, as @Charles has already pointed out is the declaration/definition of a constant method that returns a reference to an array of elements stored as a member.

The syntax is quite bizarre and could (and should probably) be simplified by means of a typedef:

```
typedef SomeEnumerated array_t[SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE];
const array_t& SomeMethod() const;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea, it's a consequence of C's utterly backwards type declaration syntax. It's similar to how, when doing an array typedef, you write this: `typedef int myArrayType[3];`, with the `[3]` after the new typename, not the original.

If you're really clever you can use `{std,tr1,boost}::array` -- worth considering anyway -- so that you end up with:

```
 array<SomeEnumeratedId, SOME_CONSTANT_VALUE>& SomeClass::SomeMethod() const;
```

instead.

The workarounds with typedefs (explored in other answers) are related, although not quite equivalent as `{std,tr1,boost}::array` are wrappers, not just typedefs.